# Eigen LDLT Cholesky decomposition in-place

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, in-place

I am trying to get Eigen3 to solve a linear system `A * X = B` with an in-place Cholesky decomposition. I cannot afford to have any temporaries of the size of `A` pushed on the stack, but I am free to destroy `A` in the process.

Unfortunately,

```
A.llt().solveInPlace(B);
```

is out of question, since `A.llt()` implicitly pushes a temporary matrix of the size of `A` on the stack. For the `LLT` case, I could get access to the necessary functionality like so:

```
// solve A * X = B in-place for positive-definite A
template <typename AType, typename BType>
void AllInPlaceSolve(AType& A, BType& B)
{
    typedef Eigen::internal::LLT_Traits<AType, Eigen::Upper> TraitsType;
    TraitsType::inplace_decomposition(A);
    TraitsType::getL(A).solveInPlace(B);
    TraitsType::getU(A).solveInPlace(B);
}
```

This works fine, but I am worried that:

- My matrices `A` might be positive semidefinite only, in which case a LDLT decomposition is required
- The `LLT` decomposition calculates `sqrt()` unnecessarily for the solution of the system

I could not find a way to hook in Eigen's LDLT functionality similarly to the code above, since the code is structured very differently.

So my question is: Is there a way to use Eigen3 for solving a linear system using LDLT decompositions using no more scratch space than for the diagonal matrix `D`?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to allocate a LDLT solver only once, and call the compute method:

```
LDLT<MatType> ldlt(size);
// ...
ldlt.compute(A);
x = ldlt.solve(b);
```

If that's also not an option, you can const cast the matrix stored by the ldlt object:

```
LDLT<MatType> ldlt(MatType::Identity(size,size));
MatType& A = const_cast<MatType&>(ldlt.matrixLDLT());
```

plays with `A`, and then:

```
ldlt.compute(A);
x = ldlt.solve(b);
```

This is ugly, but this should work as long as `MatType` is column major.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really have to use my own memory, so neither of this works. I think what I need is in `internal::ldlt_inplace<Lower>::unblocked()`, but it's less evident to setup than for the LLT case.

Comment: Also, in case I can get `unblocked()` setup, our matrices `A` are row major, but since `A` is symmetric, I should be able to just use `A.transpose()`, no?

Comment: if the matrix is complete, then, yes, you can see a row-major upper triangular part as a column-major lower triangular one. You only need to allocate a PermutationMatrix to pass it to `internal::ldlt_inplace<Lower>::unblocked()`. The main issue is that you will have to re-write the solve step.